# Search for a new "name"

Tags: names

My last name in Chinese spelling is Fang, but I find that it has a bad meaning as an English word. I tried to change it to Feng, but since they are not quite distinguishable on the pronunciation, it still may remind people of that meaning...

I was wondering whether you could help me look for a "name" that is related to Fang, but does not have a too similar pronunciation.
("Fang" means square in Chinese.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would not worry too much about a "bad meaning." It is a proper noun; people named *Green* or *Butcher* do not suffer from others thinking they are discolored or that they work in slaughterhouses. There are many people who go by Fang or Feng and there is no bad luck associated with it. Indeed if anything, *fang* could invoke an image of the strength of a wild predator. But in any case the Cantonese romanization of 方 is *Fong*, which does not sound at all like and has no meaning in English. If you do not mind people assuming you are a southerner, that may be an alternative.

Comment: As much fun as it is, helping look for good names is pretty off topic here. I'm sure there is a website somewhere that would be better at helping you there.

Comment: In English, "Fang" and "Feng" are quite distinguishable; it's only to foreigners that the sound the same.

Answer (score 3):

The English word with the bad meaning is *fang*, pronounced **/fæŋ/**. It means a long cuspid tooth, like wolves and tigers have.

Most Americans would pronounce any Chinese name presented to them spelled "Fang" as **/faŋ/**, and ***not*** as /**fæŋ**/. (There is no English word pronounced **/faŋ/**)

Moreover, about half of Americans cannot distinguish **/a/** from **/ɔ/**, so they are likely to say "Fang" as **/fɔŋ/**, as if it were spelled "Fong". (There is no English word pronounced **/fɔŋ/**, either)

Consequently, if you were to change the English spelling of your name to "Fong", the chances are that Americans, at least, could come close to pronouncing it in a way you could recognize, and nobody would connect it with wolves' canine teeth.

... though I agree with choster that such a drastic step is unlikely to be necessary.